# symmetricds SYSADMIN send-script error

Tags: database-replication, symmetricds

the command of sending a sql script to node or node group is working fine but the issue is with parsing the file itself.
    Here you are, the log of the target node

2014-08-27 16:51:12,130 ERROR [station-001] [DataLoaderService] [station-001-pull-1] Failed to load batch 000-31 because: In file: inline evaluation of: ``DROP TABLE ofep.PRODUCT_RESTRICTIONS;'' Encountered "ofep" at line 1, column 12.

java.lang.RuntimeException: In file: inline evaluation of: ``DROP TABLE ofep.PRODUCT_RESTRICTIONS;'' Encountered "ofep" at line 1, column 12.

```
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.writer.DatabaseWriter.script(DatabaseWriter.java:919)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.writer.DatabaseWriter.write(DatabaseWriter.java:196)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.writer.DatabaseWriter.write(DatabaseWriter.java:167)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.writer.NestedDataWriter.write(NestedDataWriter.java:64)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.model.ProcessInfoDataWriter.write(ProcessInfoDataWriter.java:65)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.writer.NestedDataWriter.write(NestedDataWriter.java:64)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.writer.TransformWriter.write(TransformWriter.java:217)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.DataProcessor.forEachDataInTable(DataProcessor.java:194)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.DataProcessor.forEachTableInBatch(DataProcessor.java:164)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.DataProcessor.process(DataProcessor.java:114)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataLoaderService$LoadIntoDatabaseOnArrivalListener.end(DataLoaderService.java:779)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.writer.StagingDataWriter.notifyEndBatch(StagingDataWriter.java:75)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.writer.AbstractProtocolDataWriter.end(AbstractProtocolDataWriter.java:220)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.DataProcessor.process(DataProcessor.java:124)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataLoaderService.loadDataFromTransport(DataLoaderService.java:407)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataLoaderService.loadDataFromPull(DataLoaderService.java:265)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.PullService.execute(PullService.java:129)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.NodeCommunicationService$2.run(NodeCommunicationService.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: In file: inline evaluation of: ``DROP TABLE ofep.PRODUCT_RESTRICTIONS;'' Encountered "ofep" at line 1, column 12.

```
at bsh.Parser.generateParseException(Parser.java:6068)
at bsh.Parser.jj_consume_token(Parser.java:5939)
at bsh.Parser.BlockStatement(Parser.java:2780)
at bsh.Parser.Line(Parser.java:147)
at bsh.Interpreter.Line(Interpreter.java:1000)
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:635)
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:739)
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:728)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.writer.DatabaseWriter.script(DatabaseWriter.java:916)
... 20 more
```

2014-08-27 16:51:12,470 ERROR [station-001] [DataLoaderService] [station-001-pull-1] Failed while parsing batch
java.lang.RuntimeException: In file: inline evaluation of: ``DROP TABLE ofep.PRODUCT_RESTRICTIONS;'' Encountered "ofep" at line 1, column 12.

```
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.writer.DatabaseWriter.script(DatabaseWriter.java:919)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.writer.DatabaseWriter.write(DatabaseWriter.java:196)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.writer.DatabaseWriter.write(DatabaseWriter.java:167)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.writer.NestedDataWriter.write(NestedDataWriter.java:64)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.model.ProcessInfoDataWriter.write(ProcessInfoDataWriter.java:65)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.writer.NestedDataWriter.write(NestedDataWriter.java:64)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.writer.TransformWriter.write(TransformWriter.java:217)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.DataProcessor.forEachDataInTable(DataProcessor.java:194)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.DataProcessor.forEachTableInBatch(DataProcessor.java:164)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.DataProcessor.process(DataProcessor.java:114)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataLoaderService$LoadIntoDatabaseOnArrivalListener.end(DataLoaderService.java:779)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.writer.StagingDataWriter.notifyEndBatch(StagingDataWriter.java:75)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.writer.AbstractProtocolDataWriter.end(AbstractProtocolDataWriter.java:220)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.DataProcessor.process(DataProcessor.java:124)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataLoaderService.loadDataFromTransport(DataLoaderService.java:407)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataLoaderService.loadDataFromPull(DataLoaderService.java:265)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.PullService.execute(PullService.java:129)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.NodeCommunicationService$2.run(NodeCommunicationService.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: In file: inline evaluation of: ``DROP TABLE ofep.PRODUCT_RESTRICTIONS;'' Encountered "ofep" at line 1, column 12.

```
at bsh.Parser.generateParseException(Parser.java:6068)
at bsh.Parser.jj_consume_token(Parser.java:5939)
at bsh.Parser.BlockStatement(Parser.java:2780)
at bsh.Parser.Line(Parser.java:147)
at bsh.Interpreter.Line(Interpreter.java:1000)
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:635)
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:739)
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:728)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.writer.DatabaseWriter.script(DatabaseWriter.java:916)
... 20 more
```

The script contains only one statement “DROP TABLE ofep.PRODUCT_RESTRICTIONS;”

```
Could you please help me?
```

Thanks,
Ayman

Answer (score 0):

Symadmin has three different send subcommands...

```
send-sql            Send SQL statement to node
send-schema         Send schema change to node
send-script         Send script to node
```

You used **send-script** which is used for sending [BSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeanShell) scripts.

What you want to use is **send-sql**.

Comment: Thanks a lot Austin, but what if i want to send SQL Script to delete replicated tables on nodes; How could I do that?

Comment: You would need to first remove the triggers for that replicated table. Otherwise the next time that table is replicated, depending on settings, it will either create an error or recreate the table. You could then send-sql to delete the table on the remote nodes.